# Problema ao obter retorno de DLL Delphi com Java

Tags: java, delphi-7, dll

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema em java e uma parte desse sistema precisa obter dados que vem de um outro sistema em Delphi.

Criei duas funções uma que retorna uma **String** e outra que retorna um **int**.
A função que retorna um **int** funciona perfeitamente, mas estou tendo problemas com a função que retorna uma **String**. no Delphi ela funciona perfeitamente, já quando a chamo no Java da o seguinte erro:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
at com.sun.jna.Native.invokePointer(Native Method)
at com.sun.jna.Function.invokePointer(Function.java:471)
at com.sun.jna.Function.invokeString(Function.java:652)
at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:396)
at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:316)
at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:232)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.testeString(Unknown Source)
at br.com.Teste.TesteDLL.main(TesteDLL.java:20)


//Classe Java que estende de StdCallLibrary
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;

public interface LeituraDLL extends StdCallLibrary {
    LeituraDLL leituraDLL = (LeituraDLL) Native.loadLibrary(
            "MinhaDLL", LeituraDLL.class);
    public int teste(int valor);
    public String testeString(String texto);    
}

// Function em Delph

library MinhaDLL;

uses
  SysUtils,
  Classes;
  {$R *.res}

function teste(v:Integer):Integer; stdcall;
  begin
    Result :=  v+5;
  end;
function testeString(v:Integer):String; stdcall;
  begin
    Result :=  'TesteString Ok';
  end;
exports teste;
exports testeString;


end.

//Chamada da Classe que estende de StdCallLibrary
import com.sun.jna.Native;

public class TesteDLL {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LeituraDLL leituraDLL = (LeituraDLL) Native.loadLibrary(
                "MinhaDLL", LeituraDLL.class);
        int teste = leituraDLL.teste(10);
        String testeString = leituraDLL.testeString("Ola Mundo");
        System.out.println("Retorno Function Teste: " + teste); // Retorna o valor: 15
        System.out.println("Retorno Function TesteString: " + testeString); // Exibe o erro Invalid memory access
    }

}
```

Alguém já teve esse problema e sabe como resolver?
Obs.: Estou utilizando JNA.

Comment: No Delphi você está recebendo um inteiro como parâmetro (`testeString(v:Integer)`). Já tentou alterar para `String`?

Comment: Bruno César, na verdade isso nem esta interferindo.
Consegui retornando PChar, mas ai tenho outro problema é que no Java na hora de dar um insert no banco de dados, os caracteres especiais que vem do Delphi, ele ignora e inclui outros totalmente diferentes.